# JMteter Thread Group with Login run once and use the AccessToken to run other HTTP Requests with more Users / Threads

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, access-token, jmeter-5.0, optimistic-concurrency

I am using the JMetter 5.1.1 to run load test against ASP.Net Core 2.2 with Identity framework. If I run the Login POST requests with many threads concurrently, it will result in AppIdentityDbContext optimistic concurrency exception when UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync` is called. So, I need to send a POST login request only ONCE, extracts the Access Token from the response and use it for subsequent requests with many users/threads for the load test. How to achieve this objective?

Comment: While that is possible I would recommend against it as it is an unrealistic test. It is better to use many different users and ramp up slowly (allow the logins to take some time). Otherwise just save the token in a global variable/property and make a copy to a local variable in the other tests.

Comment: I manage to save it using JSON Extractor but I only want to run the Login request ONCE. How to achieve this?

Comment: I can't just register and login with different users as the user registration is complicated which needs another admin application to approve the registration before the user could login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to do this (see comment) you can do the login in a setup thread group that runs once. Extract the tokens (access and refresh or just access) with a JSON extractor, then copy them to properties with a JSR223Assertion with groovy:

```
def p = vars.get("accessToken");
props.put("accessTokenProperty", p);
```

Then in the other thread groups, use a JSR223PreProcessor for your first sampler that copies the properties to variables, i.e.:

```
def p = props.get("accessTokenProperty");
vars.put("accessToken", p);
```

You can then use the variable $accessToken as usual:

```
Bearer ${accessToken}
```